# Windows app: get pixeldata from preview frame with javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, winjs

I'm using WinJs to create an app with javascript that get camera preview. 
With preview I get a videoframe but now I would like to get all pixel rgba data for calculate average color and other infos.
I use getPreviewFrameAsync method of Media.Capture class. Is it right?

```js
 mediaCapture.getPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame)
    .then(function (currentFrame) {
         //get pixeldata rgba of frame of camerapreview
         
     }
```

Documentation in javascript of these classes is very poor....
Thanks.

IngD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use getPreviewFrameAsync method of Media.Capture class. Is it right?

Yes, with this you can get a [videoframe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.videoframe.aspx) object. After then, you can get the [SoftwareBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn887358) object which contains the pixel data  by [VideoFrame.SoftwareBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.videoframe.softwarebitmap.aspx) property. Code like follows:

```
return oMediaCapture.getPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame)
.then(function (currentFrame) {
    // Collect the resulting frame
    var frameBitmap = currentFrame.softwareBitmap;
    // Show the frame information
    frameInfoTextBlock.textContent = frameBitmap.pixelWidth + "x" + frameBitmap.pixelHeight + " " +
        stringOfEnumeration(Windows.Graphics.DirectX.DirectXPixelFormat, frameBitmap.bitmapPixelFormat);
```

The official sample [CameraGetPreviewFrame](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame/js) provides the example written on javascript language, and it has examples about the features that you want you can reference.